# The "choose a template" modal for moderator messages is obscured on my mobile browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, responsive-design, moderator-templates

If I attempt to create a Moderator Message ("contact user privately") in my mobile browser (Chrome on Android) for Mi Yodeya, with the new responsive design, the modal that allows me to pick a message template is obscured. It is too wide to display on my screen, I can't change the magnification, and I can only scroll to the right and left a little bit. as a result, when I turn my phone sideways for maximum width, the top-right-most and bottom-left-most views of this modal available to me are:

[image: Partial view of mod message template modal]

and

[image: Partial view of mod message template modal, still missing left part]

The left portion of the modal, including the radio buttons for selecting a message and much of the message titles, is unviewable.

For my purposes, it would be sufficient to fix this by allowing full left-right scrolling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally finally finally we've gotten to fixing this - the page is now responsive and you should be able to use it on mobile with no issues.

Comment: You still had 2 years to spare before it was in 6-8 years ;)